# Regex which will find string from content and replace with HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a content like this.

```
"Test with the dummy content. Another dummy content."
```

I want regex where If I pass specific string and specific html tag then It will replace string with tag. For ex.

```
function strReplace($content, $string, $tag)
{
    // $output = regex function ...

}
```

If I call method like strReplace($content, 'dummy', 'b');

Output should be:

```
"Test with the <b>dummy</b> content. Another <b>dummy</b> content."
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are close to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution.

Tried something and it works. Using regex like

```
// $tag = '<b>'; or $tag = 'b';
$tag = str_replace('<', '', str_replace('>', '', $tag));

$output = preg_replace(array('/'.$string.'/'), array('<'.$tag.'>'.$string.'</'.$tag.'>'), $content);
```

Thanks for help still suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for `preg_split`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

You can split on the regex, receive the fragment and then insert after the first and before the last element your tags. This is probably (depending on your context) even so possible with just `str_split`.